# All joined subquery results return null

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get all customers with their latest payment transaction, including customers without any transaction:

```
SELECT c.customer_id, c.phone_number, c.email
     , p.transaction_no, p.amount, p.transaciton_datetime
FROM tbl_customers c 
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT customer_id, transaction_no, amount, transaciton_datetime
   FROM tbl_payment_transactions
   ORDER BY payment_transaction_id DESC
   LIMIT 1
) p
ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
```

The above query returns NULL for `p.transaction_no, p.amount, p.transaciton_datetime` in every row. But I can make sure that there are transactions made by customers in `tbl_payment_transactions`.

Comment: Something like that: `SELECT c.customer_id, c.phone_number, c.email, 
       p.transaction_no, p.amount, p.transaciton_datetime
FROM tbl_customers c 
LEFT JOIN tbl_payment_transactions p ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT customer_id, max(payment_transaction_id) maxtransid
  FROM tbl_payment_transactions
  GROUP BY customer_id
) p2 ON p.customer_id = p2.customer_id 
    AND p.payment_transaction_id = p2.maxtransid`

Comment: the record that the limit command selects from the p.customer_id <> c.customer_id field. But you state:- "But I can make sure that there are transactions made by customers in the tbl_payment_transactions." Show us these records

Comment: Can you share some input data ?

Answer (score 2):

You want the subquery to be run once per each different row of the driving table `tbl_customers`. This is called a *lateral subquery* and takes the form:

```
SELECT
  c.customer_id, c.phone_number, c.email,
  p.transaction_no, p.amount, p.transaciton_datetime
FROM tbl_customers c 
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT customer_id, transaction_no, amount, transaciton_datetime
  FROM tbl_payment_transactions t
  WHERE c.customer_id = t.customer_id
  ORDER BY payment_transaction_id DESC 
  LIMIT 1
) p
ON true
```

Answer (score 1):

[The Impaler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6436191/the-impaler) provided the correct form with a `LATERAL` subquery.

Alternatively, you can use `DISTINCT ON` in a subquery and a plain `LEFT JOIN`.

Performance of the latter can be better while retrieving all (or most) customers, and if there are only few transactions per customer and/or you don't have a multicolumn index on `(customer_id, payment_transaction_id)` or `(customer_id, payment_transaction_id DESC)`:

```sql
SELECT c.customer_id, c.phone_number, c.email
     , p.transaction_no, p.amount, p.transaciton_datetime
FROM   tbl_customers c 
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (customer_id)
          customer_id, transaction_no, amount, transaciton_datetime
   FROM   tbl_payment_transactions
   ORDER  BY customer_id, payment_transaction_id DESC
   ) p USING (customer_id);
```

About performance aspects:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)